# Create a query in microsoft Access?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

Create a query using all the fields from the Customers table that will show those customers who have purchased a product with the Product ID 2. Save the query as Product and close the query.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Warren. Can you please [edit] your question with a little more detail? What version of Access are you using? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE: This may be slightly different depending on what version you are using.***

Using the query wizard, select the Customer Table then use the `>>` to add all fields. Use details and then Name it what you want. Before you finish select the option to modify the query. When the query opens, place a `2` in the criteria for Product ID. Save the query and run it to see that it does what you like.

If you want to learn more about making queries in Access, [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-queries-for-a-new-database-RZ101772999.aspx) is some free training from Microsoft.